# show the values without overriding in the table with multiple method calls

Tags: java

Iam writing a piece of java code which shows the result in the html table. The same code is called multiple times with different values and i need to show all the values in the html table.Currently with my code it is overriding and showing only the last method call values in the html.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class TableTest {
    void meth1(String c1,String c2,String c3){
     //business logic
     tableCreation(String c1,String c2,String c3);
     }

    void meth2(String c1,String c2,String c3){
     //business logic
     tableCreation(String c1,String c2,String c3);
     }

    void meth3(String c1,String c2,String c3){
     //business logic
     tableCreation(String c1,String c2,String c3);
     }

    void tableCreation(String c1, String c2, String c3) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("results.html"));
            writer.write("<html>" + "<body>" + "<table border ='1'>" + "<tr>" + "<th>Col1</th>" + "<th>Col2</th>"
                    + "<th>Col3</th>" + "</tr><tr>");

            /*
             * for (int i=1;i<=3;i++) { writer.write("<td>"); //some business logic here
             * writer.write("-aaaaa-"); writer.write("</td> "); }
             */
            writer.write("<td>");
            writer.write(c1);
            writer.write("</td> ");
            writer.write("<td>");
            writer.write(c2);
            writer.write("</td> ");
            writer.write("<td>");
            writer.write(c3);
            writer.write("</td> ");
            writer.write("</tr></table>" + "</body>" + "</html>");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IO EXCEPTION-----" + e);
        }

        System.out.println("----------END---------------");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // the below method calls are dynamic, don't know how many times
        // tableCreation(..) is being called
        new TableTest().meth1("R1Tst1", "R1Tst2", "R1Tst3");
        new TableTest().meth2("R2Tst1", "R2Tst2", "R2Tst3");
        new TableTest().meth3("R3Tst1", "R3Tst2", "R3Tst3");
    }
}
```

**Result:**

```
 Col1   Col2   Col3
 R3Tst1 R3Tst2 R3Tst3
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
R1Tst1 R1Tst2 R1Tst3 
R2Tst1 R2Tst2 R2Tst3 
R3Tst1 R3Tst2 R3Tst3
```

Comment: You are creating a new table, each time. What you would like to do is to create a table and add rows.

Comment: I cannot pass writer object to the existing method tableCreation(..) as in many other areas this method is called and cannot change the method prototype..
Any other way to do this?

Comment: Another approach would be to have a Table class with three attributes: `String header`, `List<String> rows` and `String footer`. You can have a method for adding rows and a method for creating the file in which you connect the header, the rows and the footer and write it to a file. This way, each time you need to add a row, you can add it to the list and then regenerate your file.

Answer (score 2):

You could borrow from the builder pattern.

What I did below was to create an instance of the `HtmlTableBuilder` class in which the first part of the html file was added. Afterwards, you can add rows using the `add()` method and finalize with the `build()` method, which also adds the closing part of the html file and returns an instance of `HtmlTable`. This, you can write to your `BufferedWriter`.

```
public class HtmlTable {

    String html;

    public HtmlTable(String html) {
        this.html = html;
    }

    public static class HtmlTableBuilder {
        String html;

        public HtmlTableBuilder() {
            html = "<html>" +
                   "<body>" +
                   "<table border ='1'>" +
                   "<tr>" +
                   "<th>Col1</th>" +
                   "<th>Col2</th>" +
                   "<th>Col3</th>" +
                   "</tr>";
        }

        public HtmlTableBuilder addRow(String col1, String col2, String col3) {
            html += "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" +
                    col1 +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    col2 +
                    "</td><td>" +
                    col3 +
                    "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
            return this;
        }

        public HtmlTable build() {
            html += "</table>" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>";
            HtmlTable toReturn = new HtmlTable(html);
            return toReturn;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HtmlTable table = new HtmlTableBuilder()
                .addRow("R1Tst1", "R1Tst2", "R1Tst3")
                .addRow("R2Tst1", "R2Tst2", "R2Tst3")
                .addRow("R3Tst1", "R3Tst2", "R3Tst3")
                .build();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("results.html"));
        writer.write(table);
        writer.close();
    }

}
```

This is for a table with three columns. Of course you can use your imagination and convert this into a more generic solution with a non-predefined number of columns. In that case, you would for example make use of a list of `Strings` in the `add()` method.

Comment: Hope you forgive me I did not include a try-catch block in this example...

Comment: +1 for all your inputs..thats my bad..i wanted to make it simple and written a sample TableTest class..Please see the modified TableTest above..new TableTest().meth1("R1Tst1", "R1Tst2", "R1Tst3"); is called and in meth1 the table creation logic is being called..Hope you forgive me..

Comment: I guess you could still use my approach, but instead of a single `add()` method, you would have an `add1()`, `add2()` and `add3()` in the `HtmlTableBuilder` class. Alternatively, you will have three methods that do the business logic separately and return a new list of three `Strings` that can then be passed to the `add()` method.

Comment: Sorry I cannot use your code as I mentioned in my code comments above that the calls are dynamic and don’t know how many times the calls are made..